# Is it idiomatic to use a label of the size of an item of clothing as an adjective?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> I'm looking for a size large sweater?

Is it idiomatic to use a label of the size of an item of clothing as an adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Your example sentence is fine. You could also give a number, like "I'm looking for a size 6 sweater."